# Abrir nueva ventana de google maps

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

estoy haciendo una app que me muestra un listado de mis clientes, haciendo filtros por nombre, apellidos etc.., he puesto un boton para que me abra una ventana nueva de google maps y me enseña su dirección, pero el problema es que siempre me muestra la direccion del primer item, pulse el que pulse. Alguien puede ayudarme. Os dejo el codigo html y js. Gracias

```
        <section class="contenedor">
        <?php foreach ($clientes as $cliente) : ?>
            <div>
                <div class="1 mt-2">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header dark-mode">
                            <div name="nombre" class="header-bar d-flex accordion">
                                <h4 class="main-title-purple p-2 mt-1"><?php echo $cliente->nombre . ' ' . $cliente->apellidos; ?></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel">
                                <div class="pl-5 mr-3 pb-2 dark-mode">
                                    <div class="row" id="buscador">
                                        <div class="col-12" name="direccion" ><i class="fas fa-caret-right" style="color:white;"></i> <b>Dirección: <span id="direccion"> <?php echo $cliente->direccion; ?> - <?php echo $cliente->localidad; ?> (<?php echo $cliente->provincia; ?>)</span> </b></div>
                                        <div class="col-12"><i class="fas fa-caret-right" style="color:white;"></i> <b>Teléfono: <a href="tel:<?php echo $cliente->telefono; ?>"></b><?php echo $cliente->telefono ?></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12"><i class="fas fa-caret-right" style="color:white;"></i> <b>Correo electrónico: <a href="mailto:<?php echo $cliente->email; ?>"><?php echo $cliente->email; ?></b></a> </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 my-2">
                                            <a onclick="return mostrarLugar();" 
                                                type="button" class="btn btn-warning fas fa-plane"  
                                                ref="https://www.google.cl/maps/preview" 
                                                target="_blank">Mostrar Mapa</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 my-2">
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#masinfo">Mas Información</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </section>
```

Este es el JS

```
function mostrarLugar() {
  let direction = document.getElementById('direccion');
  console.log(direction);
  if (direction) {
    window.open('https://google.cl/maps/place/' + direction.textContent, '_blank');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás usando el mismo ID para cada elemento y, los [ID deben ser únicos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/id); lo que está pasando es que `document.getElementById('id-repetido')` siempre te va a devolver el primero que encuentre.

Entonces, hay que asignar clase al elemento deseado y enviar el evento a la función, aunque hay mejores opciones que comentaré después:

```
                        <div class="panel">
                            <div class="pl-5 mr-3 pb-2 dark-mode">
                                <div class="row" id="buscador">
                                    <div class="col-12" name="direccion" ><i class="fas fa-caret-right" style="color:white;"></i> <b>Dirección: <span class="direccion"> <?php echo $cliente->direccion; ?> - <?php echo $cliente->localidad; ?> (<?php echo $cliente->provincia; ?>)</span> </b></div>
                                    <div class="col-12"><i class="fas fa-caret-right" style="color:white;"></i> <b>Teléfono: <a href="tel:<?php echo $cliente->telefono; ?>"></b><?php echo $cliente->telefono ?></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-12"><i class="fas fa-caret-right" style="color:white;"></i> <b>Correo electrónico: <a href="mailto:<?php echo $cliente->email; ?>"><?php echo $cliente->email; ?></b></a> </div>
                                    <div class="col-12 my-2">
                                        <a onclick="mostrarLugar(event);" 
                                            type="button" class="btn btn-warning fas fa-plane"  
                                            href="https://www.google.cl/maps/preview" 
                                            target="_blank">Mostrar Mapa</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-12 my-2">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#masinfo">Mas Información</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

En Javascript, desde el evento vas a tomar el enlace que lo disparó, de ahí accedes al ancestro común con (div con clase panel), usando [.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) y, finalmente, buscas la dirección (span con clase direccion), usando [.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
// Recibes el evento como parámetro
function mostrarLugar(e) {
    // Cancela el comportamiento normal del evento
    e.preventDefault();
    // Desde el evento obtienes el enlace que recibió clic: (e.target)
    // Y luego el ancestro
    let parent = e.target.closest('.panel');
    // Desde el ancestro obtienes la dirección por clase
    let direction = parent.querySelector('.direccion');
    console.log(direction);
    if (direction) {
        // Es probable que debas eliminar espacios al inicio y final del valor
        // Si es el caso, la variable quedaría: direccion.textContent.trim()
        window.open('https://google.cl/maps/place/' + direction.textContent, '_blank');
    }
}
```

Una mejor opción para evitar tener la función directamente en cada enlace es "delegar" el evento al contenedor padre, donde vas a analizar el elemento que recibió clic y, si se trata de un enlace para abrir el mapa, entonces llamar la función.

En HTML, el enlace queda más limpio:

```
                                    <div class="col-12 my-2">
                                        <a type="button" class="btn btn-warning fas fa-plane"  
                                            href="https://www.google.cl/maps/preview" 
                                            target="_blank">Mostrar Mapa</a>
                                    </div>
```

El contenedor de todos los registros es `<section class="contenedor">` y ahí es donde vas a escuchar los clics, solo asegúrate de que es el único elemento con esa etiqueta y clase en todo el documento, de lo contrario, es probable que no funcione el siguiente código:

```
let container = document.querySelector('section.container');
container.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // ¿Es un enlace con clase btn-warning?
    if(e.target.tagName == 'a' && e.target.classList.contains('btn-warning')) {
        // Ejecutar la función enviando el evento como parámetro
        mostrarLugar(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Triby, lo he conseguido hacer con tu primera solución, la segunda no se que estoy haciendo mal que no me funciona. El unico pero que queda es que cuando me abre la nueva ventana de google maps con la dirección tengo que darle a la lupa para que la localice, si estoy en un dispositivo móvil con la app de google maps no hay lupa y lo que hace es que se queda pensando. No se si eso se puede controlar desde mi código.